# OSE switch to application from mobile device

Tags: macos, window-manager, mobile-device-management

Is there a **mobile app** that lets you view the list applications you're currently running on a computer you're using?

For instance, my mobile device would connect as a **client** to my MacBook Pro, and have live info about what's running and which app I'm currently using:

[image: MobileAltTab]

Showing the currently selected app similar to OSX's **alt tab** functionality, and when I touch a particular app, it becomes **selected** and in the foreground.